# php regexp problems

Tags: php, regex

I am doing a simple tutorial which able to catch the keywords automatically, the code is as below:-

```
$content = "#abc i love you #def #you , and you?";
preg_match_all("/[\n\r\t]*\#(.+?)\s/s",$content, $tag_matches);
print_r($tag_matches);

output:-
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => #abc [1] => #def [2] => #you ) [1] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def [2] => you ) )

'#' symbol with words are the keywords
```

the output is correct, but if I insert any punctuation symbols beside the keyword, e.g: #you, , the output will become you, , may I know how do I filter punctuation symbols after keywords?

besides this, if I insert any keywords together just like #def#you, , the output is def#you, is anyone can help me to separate it/

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` instead of whitespace `\s`. That will stop the match when it reaches anything other than a word character (i.e., `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

```
/[\n\r\t]*\#(.+?)\b/s
```

Conceptually, that's what you were trying to do anyway by putting whitespace there (i.e., denote end of word).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
    /[\n\r\t]*\#([\w]*)\s/s
```

The * actually has the same behavior as +?. By matching the . you are every character. If you have tags which are hyphenated you may want to add - inside of the brackets.

Comment: _"* actually has the same behavior as +?"_ Actually, it is different. You're thinking of `(.+)?`. `+?` is a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), meaning it's a `+` that stops at the smallest match rather than being as greedy as possible. `*` is "0 or more; as many as possible" while `+?` is "1 or more; as few as possible".